# JFrame: Waiting for button press on form to receive values in class and continue

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouseevent

I'm making a simple game. I have a class called GraphicalInterface, and a JFrame class FrmMain which extends GraphicalInterface with some values that I want to send from FrmMain to GraphicalInterface when a JButton btnNewGame in FrmMain is clicked. However, when I open a FrmMain object to choose the settings, I need the subsequent code to wait until btnNewGame is clicked and the FrmMain closed.

I have searched around including StackOverflow but I haven't found any relevant solutions. The best idea I have right now is to use a dialog, but I'm not confident that it would be appropriate for my menu or how I should implement it in this case, having never used it before.
Furthermore,  I want to use the solution for this problem for another JFrame called FrmGame which should also send values to GraphicalInterface on certain inputs, but not close itself when it does so.

Here is the relevant code for GraphicalInterface, a subclass of an abstract class IOInterface.

```
public class GraphicalInterface extends IOInterface{
protected FrmMain mainMenu;
protected FrmGame gameInterface;
private Settings settings;

@Override
public void initialise(){
    round = new Round(ioInterface);
    round.initialise(getSettings());

    board = round.getBoard();
    turnCount = round.getTurnCount();
    turnCount++;
    round.setTurnCount(turnCount);
    displayBoard();
}

@Override
public Settings getSettings() {
    openMainMenu();
    return settings;
}

@Override
public void playTurn() {
    while (!round.getGameOver()) {
        round.guess();
        turnCount++;
    }
}

private void openMainMenu(){
    if (mainMenu == null){
        mainMenu = new FrmMain();
    }
    mainMenu.setVisible(true);
    mainMenu.toFront();

    //I need the code to wait here for the user to pick their settings on 
    //FrmMain and press btnNewGame before the settings below are retrieved from it


    int pegCount = mainMenu.sldPegs.getValue();
    int colourCount = mainMenu.sldColours.getValue();
    int mode = mainMenu.lstMode.getSelectedIndex();

    settings = new Settings(pegCount, colourCount, mode);
    settings.calculateRows();
    }
}
```

And here is the code from FrmMain

```
public class FrmMain extends GraphicalInterface{
private JPanel contentPane;

JButton btnNewGame;

public FrmMain() {
    setTitle("Mastermind");
    setResizable(false);
    initialiseComponents();
}

private void updateToolTips() {
    int mode = lstMode.getSelectedIndex();

    if (mode == 0 || mode == 1)
        lblToolTipA.setText("Human Codebreaker");
    else lblToolTipA.setText("AI Codebreaker");

    if (mode == 1 || mode == 3)
        lblToolTipB.setText("AI Codemaker");
    else lblToolTipB.setText("Human Codemaker");
 }

private void btnNewGameClick(){
    this.dispose();
}

private void initialiseComponents() {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 321, 387);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    btnNewGame = new JButton("New Game");
    btnNewGame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            btnNewGameClick();
        }
    });
    btnNewGame.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    btnNewGame.setBounds(155, 188, 137, 25);
    contentPane.add(btnNewGame);
    }
}
```

Here is a picture of my incomplete FrmMain.

[image]

So, how should I retrieve the values from the JFrame into the main GUI class GraphicalInterface, suspending the code until the New Game button is clicked?

Note:
Currently, FrmMain extends up through several classes which finally imports javax.swing.JFrame. I don't know if FrmMain needs to extend GraphicalInterface or if it should simply extends JFrame directly.

GraphicalInterface used to implement an interface IOInterface. Now, IOInterface is an abstract class so I could use fields which GraphicalInterface and another class could inherit.

Comment: Use a modal dialog, which is the generally suggest solution to this problem

Comment: Have a look at [How to make a dialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

Answer (score 2):

In generally, if you need your code to wait while you collect information from the user you should make use of a modal dialog, it allows you to collect a small amount of information from the user, while it blocks the codes execution at the point the dialog was made visible, until it is closed.

Take a look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

You will need to design a solution which allows your code to get the information from the other form but also determine when the user has cancelled or closed the window.

Generally speaking, you should not be extending from top level containers like `JFrame` or `JDialog` and instead, basing your UI forms on something like `JPanel`, this way, you can add them to what ever container you want to.

Comment: Well no, not really.  The code in `openMainMenu()` manipulates Swing components, so it needs to run on the EDT.  If you block the EDT then you freeze the GUI.  You could use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`, or else open a custom modal dialog, but neither of those prevents the rest of the code of `openMainMenu()` from running.  Indeed, since `openMainMenu()` must run on the EDT, preventing the rest of it from running is exactly what you must *not* do.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think you need to do more research into how modal dialogs work. The dialog, when made visible, will block the code at the point the where `setVisible` was called, this is done by the dialog taking over the event dispatching process to block the code execution WITHOUT block the EDT, it's how it prevents focus from been moved to another (parent) window.  This is all very safe and I've been exactly this for 16+ years within the EDT without issue.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  A modal dialog is an excellent way to gather information from the user where the execution of the code is depended upon the results of that information been gathered from the user (ie you want to update the UI or have the user make a decision)

Comment: @JohnBollinger And based upon the comments: `//I need the code to wait here for the user to pick their settings on FrmMain and press btnNewGame before the settings below are retrieved from it` a modal dialog is EXACTLY what the OP needs

Comment: Ok, I hereby eat a crow Big Mac.  I nevertheless maintain that what the OP *says* he wants, he cannot have exactly as he says.  He needs to *alter his GUI's appearance* to achieve a genuine interruption of his method (by displaying a modal dialog).  On the other hand, he can have the GUI appearance and behavior he wants, without any additional windows, by structuring his code differently.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I haven't looked deeply into the code, but I tend to agree that the design will probably need some rework :P